# Project Gantt with roll up/down Tableau

Tags: task, project, tableau-api, gantt-chart

I have done quite a few Gantt Charts in Tableau,  but this one is stumping me.

I am trying to create a project type Gantt chart that displays the project level due date at the top of each grouping. This should show the due date from the case and the duration so far.  That works fine until I attempt the next part which is to allow the consumer to click on that bar and have the tasks roll down with each of their project and in many cases actual durations.  (scheduled start and finish if not completed and actual start and finish if it is)

The problem is that Tableau wants to make the Project an aggregate of the tasks' durations.  I need to show what we specced the project out to, then the actual task break down so we can see where we are misjudging our estimates.  Also would like a dropline for today that goes to x axis and one for when project is due that goes to the pane axis for the project. Yes of course there are multiple projects being plotted across the departments as well.  Has anyone ever done something like this in Tableau? Any idea how I can get this to stop summing the tasks and use the project projected duration?

Thanks in advance,
Karen E. Hannum

Comment: Why are you using Tableau for project management? It's like using Excel as a text editor, you can do it, but it's not by far the best tool to do that

Comment: It is  part of a  much  larger dashboard and the requirement of  the user.

Comment: Okay, if switching to an actual project management software is not a problem, please show what your table looks like, what you have done, and what you want to achieve. I have a feeling that what you need is to group fields in an hierarchy, but I cannot be sure until you show us the data